# Where are the Windows Start Menu settings stored?

Tags: windows-7, backup, start-menu

When installing windows on a new PC, it's kind of annoying to go through all the start menu options and update them with sane (in my opinion) options either from a screenshot or from another machine where I already have proper settings.

Where does Windows store those options? Maybe it's a registry key? Probably it is. But I don't know which one. I'd like to know which key it is (or which file in case it's not in the registry) so I can export it and import it on a newly installed Windows.

[image: wow, such screenshot, much pretty]

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately they are mixed in with various other keys and data under

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\
```

For example, under the `Advanced` key you will see many of them beginning with "Start"